# Why did I need to *reboot* to change my group membership

Tags: 18.04, user-management, groups

Attempting to install MythTV on Ubuntu 18.04, I ran...

```
sudo usermod -a -G mythtv roger
```

...and logged out and back in. This [should be sufficient](https://askubuntu.com/a/250727/158095). But: my group memberships didn't change.

**I had to reboot. Why?**

Comment: Could very well be the cause in the linked dupe. systemd strikes again, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Likely because [/etc/gshadow](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man5/gshadow.5.html) was not updated (but don't ask me why that didn't happen as usermod should do that too; check /var/log/ if there is a notice). The 2 files important for groups are `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow` where gshadow supersedes group.

When both are correct logging out and in is enough to update the group for the user. If only the 1st was updated you will need to reboot or you can update gshadow with the [grpconv](https://linux.die.net/man/8/grpconv) command. Logging out and in is then enough.

Comment: Why does reboot fix it then?

Comment: A bug in systemd where they created a fix during boot